# Using data returned from methods

Tags: c#, methods

Please help me understand this if you can. I am only a few months into studying C# and seem to be missing something. I understand how to create methods, but can't seem to be able to retrieve the data to use outside of them. Please see this example I just created, trying to create a method that generates a number from 1 to 20 and then overwrite an existing variable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _170227
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          int  x = 0;

            d20();
            Console.WriteLine(x);

        }


        static int d20()
        {
            Random myRandom = new Random();
            int x = myRandom.Next(20) + 1;
            return x;


        }

    }

}
```

What do I need to do to have a method manipulate existing variables or generate data from a method for some further use not defined in the method itself?   Thank you in advance!

Comment: `d20();` -> `x = d20();`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(d20());`

Comment: In addition to `x = d20()`, if I were you, I would rename `x` *inside `d20()`, and only inside `d20()`* to `y` or `charltonHeston` or absolutely anything in the world other than `x`, just to keep straight the fact that the `x` that you declare inside `d20()` is totally unrelated to any other `x` anywhere, and the similarity in the names is a coincidence that has no meaning or significance.

Comment: A subject of interest that explains why this is happening is `scope`. Both of the integers named `x` have local scope, that is they only exist within the method in which they are defined.

Comment: Thank you all so much!  It makes much more sense to me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` inside the `d20()` method is not the same variable as the `x` in the scope from which you invoke `d20`. You need to tell the compiler that you would like to have the output from `d20` stored inside the latter, with an assignment:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;

    x = d20();
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

You can declare and assign `x` in the same statement if you like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = d20();
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just assign the return value of method to x variable like this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int  x = 0;

      x = d20();
      Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    static int d20()
    {
        Random myRandom = new Random();
        int x = myRandom.Next(20) + 1;
        return x;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To explain *why* this is happening you need to understand **scope**.

In your example you declare `x` with what is called *local scope*. That is to say that `x` only exists within the method in which you declared it.

In this example, `x` only exists within the method named `Main`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int  x = 0;
}
```

If your method named `d20` looked like this you'd get a compile time error saying that `x` was not defined.

```
static int d20()
{
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    x = myRandom.Next(20) + 1; // Error would occur here
    return x;
}
```

This is because `d20` has its own scope which is separate from `Main`.

There are a few different answers:

The shortest is simply `Console.WriteLine(d20());`. This tells the program to print the result returned from the method `d20`.

Alternatively you could restructure your code like this which assigns the result of `d20` to `x`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = d20();
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

static int d20()
{
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    return myRandom.Next(20) + 1;
}
```

Lastly you can use a higher scope by declaring `x` outside of `Main`.

```
int x;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
       d20();
       Console.WriteLine(x);
}

static void d20()
{
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    x = myRandom.Next(20) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your the value returned by the method to your variable.

Try

```
int x = d20();
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the fact that both of your methods have a variable named `x` in them is, from the compiler's perspective, purely coincidental - they definitely won't refer to the same thing. As an analogy, I know several people with the same first name as me, but they're *not* me.

As others have indicated, you need to store the return value of `d20()` in a variable (i.e. `int x = d20();`).